# transfer GoogleSignInAccout to kotlin side from flutter below flutter method chanel

Tags: flutter, kotlin, google-signin, googlesigninaccount

I want to pass the 'GoogleSignInAccount' object to kotlin via the invokeMethod - flutter method chanel. On the kotlin side, count and use this object. But when transmitting, I get the error 'ArgumentError (Invalid argument: Instance of 'GoogleSignInAccount')'
How can I transfer and is it possible to transfer objects at all ?
[error what i recive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOg3E.png)

the error occurs in this line. I was looking for an example of transferring objects, but I didn't find them. I tried to write to map, and pass an array. but the error is the same

```
final  decoded = json.decode(await platform.invokeMethod('readFitData', googleUser));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to stringify your payload as method channel only accepts certain native data type alternatively you can use https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon

[image]

More details can be found here https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-kotlin-tab

Comment: if you would have provided more detailed code I would have been able to guide you on how to fix it.

Comment: thank you for this information, it's like a breath of fresh air for me.
And thank you for offering to help, I want to study and try pigeon myself, and I will write to you if I fail)

Comment: no worries, let me know if you face any issue, if my answer is helpful to you I would highly appreciate if you can accept it.